# Почему при запуске этого кода через Python и ввода данных окно просто закрывается и не выводит результат?

Tags: python, файлы

```
a = input()
a = int(a)
b = a
c = []
x = 2
while x <= b:
    if b % x == 0:
        c.append(x)
        b = b // x
    else:
        x += 1
print(c)
```

Comment: Т.к. код рабочий, скорее всего вы просто не успеваете увидеть результат. Как вы запускаете код?

Comment: А какие значения вы вводите?

Comment: Как вы запускаете? Какая среда? Какая операционная система? Программа позволяет ввести число? Что будет если вы добавите ещё один ввод в конце программа?

Answer (score 0):

Запускайте через командную строку:

```bash
python3 my_script.py my_arg_1 my_arg_2 my_arg_3
```

Comment: Постарайтесь делать ваши ответы более развёрнутыми и добавлять в них больше объяснения. Подробнее [в справке](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Ответ можно отредактировать кнопкой «[править](//ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1488313/edit)».